# MVC Razor view DisplayFor text contents <sup</sup>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How do we display superscript inside an @HTML.DisplayFor textbox?

I have the object like this:

```
<DisplayName("Equation")>
<AllowHtml>
Public Property EquationHTML As String
```

The view says this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.EquationHTML)
```

The string contents are:

Q=0.3*(CDA[sup]0.6]/sup])*(MAP[sup]2.138[/sup])

(pretend that the square brackets are angle brackets, it turns out that this bulletin board understand the sup tag.

Any Ideas?

Comment: The BB might understand `[sup]...[/sup]` but HTML won't. The BB will be converting that to HTML on the server.

Comment: I tried changing the angle brackets into &gt; &lt; and got this:

Q=0.0126*(CDA&gt;sup&lt;0.579&gt;/sup&lt;)*(MAP&gt;sup&lt;2.824&gt;/sup&lt;)

Comment: That might be a different equation, but the concept is the same.

Comment: You should try `@Html.Raw(Model.EquationHTML)`

Comment: That gave me something like: [System.Object.System.String]  not exactly what I was looking for.  nice try though.  I tried wrapping the helper in a server.htmlEncode tag, my idea didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read DavidG's answer close enough.
I tried:

```
@Html.Raw(Function(modelItem) item.EquationHTML)
```

David was trying to tell me to drop the lambda like this:

```
@Html.Raw(item.EquationHTML)
```

So when you use the Raw helper, strike the lambda function.